# How to logged the user clicks by sponsored links without javascript

Tags: java, apache, logging, trace, ads

I'm developing web site on java.

Site contains some texts and sponsored links.

I need to traced user click by sponsored links without javascript.

How can do that?

**PS: Requirement of sponsored links provider is redirect to there server directly without us servlets or filters.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make the links point to a servlet ( or similar ) that redirects the user to the correct website and count the redictions in that servlet

Comment: I think about it, but unfortunately I can't do it because the requirement of sponsored link provider is redirect to there server directly without us servlets or filters

Comment: Why do they care if the redirect comes from the browser or your web app?

Comment: Because users must see the correct sponsored link url not us servlet. It's requirement.

Comment: You want to serve direct links to the client, don't use javascript, and yet know they followed the link... Good luck.

Comment: oh... are no miracles =)

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have used a javascript function to call a servlet to track the links.  Logging has to come first to be sure it is run.   The logging call doesn't need to be synchronous or even check for a response.  Here is some pseudo-code:

```
SITE.logSite = function(url){
    //code here to call the servlet
}

SITE.redirectSite = function(url){
    location.href=url;
}

SITE.doLogAndRedirect = function(url){
    this.logSite(url);
    this.redirectSite(url);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I can't use of javascript)

Comment: If you can't use javascript and you can't redirect, I am not sure there are any available solutions, which is why I suppose you don't have more answers.  The only thing I could think of immediately, is to ask the targetUrl to ack back to a servlet.